# Specific keyboard event

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm using Vue and I have the Quill editor inside a div (which is why I'm using the deprecated `DOMSubtreeModified`), and I want to fire an event to send an API request to save the content of the editor to the database.

Right now, below is what I have but it doesn't register backspace when I delete a character. I also don't want to recognize arrow keys when someone is moving around the editor.

What's the best way to handle this?

```
<div
  @DOMSubtreeModified="saveFunction($event)">
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using simple JavaScript:

```
var myElem = document.querySelector('#myElem');
myElem.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Backspace") {
        //Do Something
    }
    else {
        //Do Something (Or Not)
    } 
});
```

Or even jQuery:

```
$('#myElem').on('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Backspace") {
        //Do Something
    }
});
```

myElem doesn't even have to be a text box, it could be a `<div>` with no `contenteditable` properties!
The `event.key` is the newer standard than `event.keyCode` or `event.which`. That is, according to Mozilla Docs.

Hope that helps...

Edit:
This link is still under development but it shows how to register the Arrow Keys and even Shift:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#Example